# Persist CMultiFileUpload selection through input validation

Tags: yii

I'm using a CMultiFileUpload control in one of my forms like this:

```
$this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
  'name' => 'neueAnhaenge',
));
```

When input validation for some other form element fails and the input form is rendered again, a previous selection in this control is gone (as expected).

How do I repopulate this control, what do I have to do in my controller, is there a way to prepopulate this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For file fields it is rather impossible to reset the values assigned to it after it has been sent to the server.

One way to solve this would be to get the uploaded files, store them temporarily on the server and modify the form so it sends a reference to the file on the server.

A much better way would be to use Ajax or Client side validation of form fields to ensure no validation error occures when form has been sent. You can enable these options for `CActiveForm`: `$enableClientValidation` and `$enableAjaxValidation`.